# Dynamic Modal without refreshing page via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to fill a modal with dynamic data based on a form input, without a page reload.

Step by step:

1) User will input a name and submit form on admin.php

2) Data is submitted via Ajax (ideally) and processed via editUser.php

3) Data is pulled from a mysqli database and put in a modal content

4) Modal is loaded (While still viewing the admin.php page) with no page reload, but with the dynamic content in the modal.

My code so far:
Form + Ajax:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
            <script> 
                // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
                $(document).ready(function() { 
                    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
                    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                        alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
                    }); 
                }); 
            </script>
            <form id="myForm" action="query/editUser.php" method="post"> 
                Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
            </form>
```

editUser.php:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            --List data based on the form input from before
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My current problem is that I do not know how to show the modal after the form is submitted.
You will notice I currently have no calls to my database, or filling any content on the modal, because that will come later. My goal right now is to make the modal show after the form is submitted (And doing this in a way where it is still possible to fill the modal before it is shown).

I'm stuck, have been trying to figure this out for awhile, and would much appreciate help.

Edit:

Here is a breakdown of what I have, and what I want.

Right now, I've got 2 pages: `admin.php` and `editUser.php`

The admin page holds the form on it, that when submitted uses "action" to post to the editUser page, which has the code for my modal.

When the form is posted, I want the modal to be dynamically filled with information (based on the input from the admin page) using a while statement pulling information from a database.

I then want the modal to show as an overlay on the admin page - this should all happen with absolutely no page refreshing.

I KNOW how to fill the modal with information dynamically, I KNOW how to call a modal, but I DO NOT know how to show the modal on my admin page, after submitting a form and then filling the modal that is saved on the userEdit page DYNAMICALLY.

Answer (score 0):

If `dialog` is the ID of the `<div class="modal">` that's going to receive the content,

```
$('#dialog').modal('show');
```

e.g.:

```
$.get(url).then(function(data) {
    // fill "#dialog .modal-body" with content based on 'data'
    ...

    $('#dialog').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. I'm extremely new to jquery, ajax, and javascript in general. I can fill the content with a while statement, I just need a way to activate the modal from the editUser.php page after form submission. The modal is currently stored on the ajax url output page, which I can then use to fill the content of the modal, but the trouble then is to show the modal.

Comment: modals aren't activated by the PHP code, they're triggered by the client side jQuery code that submits the form and retrieves the result

Comment: I never said anything about activating the modal via php. I know how they are activated, the modal in my code already works. It just doesn't work the way I want it to. Right now, it only works if I physically open the `editUser.php` page. I want the modal to pop up when the form is submitted via the `admin.php` page.

Comment: right, so you're using this third party `ajaxForm` plugin - didn't spot that before.   You need to arrange for the callback that you registered with `ajaxForm` to retrieve the HTML output from the php _if it can - that's not clear from the docs_, then add that to the DOM, and _then_ call `.modal('show')`

Comment: I'm not in a position to work on this just now, but you need to look at the parameters that the `ajaxForm` callback receives, and see if any of those are the HTML output.

Comment: The ajaxForm plugin is not something I necessarily HAVE to use, if I could meet my goal without it easier, then I am fine with that.
Why is it not possible to run code from the form "action" attribute page? That's really what I need to do.

Comment: it's umm, "unusual" to drop new code into a page.  All of the required code should be on the page already, and the response from the PHP script should just contain data (perhaps even in JSON format) that the existing code then renders into the modal.

Comment: Is it possible to use jquery to reload a div after the data is posted? My idea is make the modal on my admin.php page, and to use editUser.php to create a $_SESSION variable, then reload the div the modal is in and then show it that way?

Comment: @Grumpy no, don't do that.   By all means put the HTML for the modal in `admin.php`, but have your `editUser.php` just handle the edits and return a response.  Then within the `admin.php` JS code, read that response, populate the `.modal-body` from that response, then `.modal('show')`

Comment: The modal is meant to show options for user editing, not to handle the editing itself. The first form is going to be just choosing the user that you want to edit.